2 Oseh Shaloms for the price of one?
One finishes both Shmone Esre and Kaddish with the very same "Oseh Shalom", often including 3 steps back.
One can say Kaddish before one said Shmone Esre's "Oseh Shalom"
When the Kaddish definitely involves 3 steps back, and one says "Oseh Shalom" for Kaddish, before one has said it for Shmone Esre, does it count for Shmoneh Esre too?
Or should one say it without taking 3 steps back, and then when finished, say it again for Shmone Esre?

Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83822/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15755/759 seemingly no matter how many things you are doing at once, when you finally take leave you've left.

A group of blessings is always ending with Amein, i.e. the chazon's Amein at the end of Oseh Shalom Kadish is also the ending of the Shemoneh Esrei. (It is in Brachos discussion of Boneh Yerushalaim blessing birkas hamazon).

I don't have a source but I would suspect this shouldn't change anything as the steps back and the words are for two separate purposes
