# Exactly how should the shaliach bow for Barachu?

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, synagogue

In every synagogue I have been in, the shaliach zibur has bowed in some way at Barachu. I presume there must be a foundation for this. If so, there should be a correct way to bow. I am seeking clarity on this.

The Mishnah Berurah in Laws of Prayer simin 57 describes barachu as said by the shaliach tzibor (ie the leader of the community prayer) but does not mention bowing.  Where is bowing during Barachu covered in the MB (or elsewhere in halacha) and what is the correct way for the Shaliach Zibur to bow?

(In contrast, bowing during the amidah is covered in the MB in detail in #113.)

My question is more specific, asking about the correct *way* to bow, than [this similar question that asks about if one should bow and sources for doing so.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13969/bowing-during-barechu.)

Answer (score 4):

Artscroll (Hebrew siddur) brings a Daas Torah in Orach Chaim siman 56 quoting a Kol Bo siman 7 who writes "when the Chazzan says Barchu he bows (כורע) and straightens up by the name of Hashem. And such is common practice."

Comment: How prevalent is this method, in your experience?  My recollection is that perhaps half of the time the bowing is done this way. The other half it is done differently, mostly bowing thru the whole sentence.

Comment: @Yehuda it's usually the same people that stand up by Hashem's name in Modim. More the yeshiva type.

Comment: The yeshiva's do not hold by what you cited?

Comment: @Yehuda What i meant was it seems in general the Yeshiva type bow in this manner. Not necessarily yeshivish yeshiva type. But the more learned amongst all types. Why? Did they see it in the artscroll?:) I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Kitzur S.A. [Yalkut Yosef 57:8](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_4.html#HtmpReportNum0012_L2) says that the Chazan should bow "a bit" with the word Barchu and stand up at Hashem's name.

The Kehot annotated siddur [says](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16091&st=&pgnum=92&hilite=) to remain bowed the entire Barchu and then bow again at Baruch and stand up at Hashem's name.

Comment: If the shaliach zibur remains bowed for the entire Borachu, how does the shaliach zibur bow again at baruch? In any case, Kehot is sefardic, right?

Comment: @YehudaW, he stands up while the congregation responds to Baruchu, so he is ready to bow again. Kehot is Chabad.

Comment: Yalkut Yosef is sefardic, right?

Comment: @yehudaw, yes, it is.