# How and when bow during first sentence of Borachu?

Tags: chazzan-prayer-leader

In Ashkanazic shuls I have seen the shaliach tzibur (leader) bow various ways during the first line of the Borachu: (a) knees first and then from the waist, (b) just from the waist, and (c) no bowing at all.  Also, sometimes the shaliach straightens up before saying HaShem, other times he remains bowed until after saying HaShem.  This practice is not consistent even with one shul.  Is there a proper approach to this bowing (during the first sentence of the Borachu)?  Are there multiple proper approaches to this bowing?  (Sources preferred.)

Comment: Regarding Tefilah, Berakhot 12a tells you that you should straighten up as you mention the Divine Name. I assume that it should be similar for those who are bowing for Barekhu, but it's a minhag. See this for sources:
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59010/exactly-how-should-the-shaliach-bow-for-barachu